# React : Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, reactstrap

Im currently trying to import my Navbar into a new project. I created a Navbar using the state hook.

```
export default function Heading() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false); 
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar color="light" fixed="top" light expand="md">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onclick={setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />
        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav className="me-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">
                GitHub
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <UncontrolledDropdown inNavbar nav>
              <DropdownToggle caret nav>
                Options
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu end>
                <DropdownItem>Option 1</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>Option 2</DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem divider />
                <DropdownItem>Reset</DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <NavbarText>Simple Text</NavbarText>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
```

}

I am importing this in my App.tsx like this

```
import Heading from "./modules/Heading";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Heading/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But im getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is highly likely with the `onclick` in your `NavbarToggler` component.

Usually in React, `onclick` event handler usually takes in a FUNCTION, not a FUNCTION CALL. Therefore, you should change to

```js
<NavbarToggler onClick={() => setIsOpen(currentState => !currentState)} />
```

This small change creates an arrow function that will do the same as before. However, the difference is that this is only a function definition, meaning it is not called yet (and is just existing)

Comment: Thank you! now i can see my Navbar but it isnt Opening/Closing :(

Comment: You can see all the code used, further on, when i write onclick im getting an error which resolves when changing it to onClick

Answer (score 0):

It's missing an arrow function in NavbarToggler onClick Event . I guess will solve the problem